# Formula to strip fraction values from text strings?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

My company has a lot of odd sizes that get specified via text strings, and we have a spreadsheet that does not currently have a calculation to strip these for use in a second column (which uses the raw number values.)  Example strings below:

24 1/2 x 23 1/4 x 1 - EXACT
29 1/4 x 13 1/2 x 1 - EXACT
19 x 35 x 1

And so on.  I had a partially complete formula to extract the leading value up to the first X, but cannot figure out an efficient way to extract the second value.   My initial formula (which I've lost, unfortunately) was using a combination of Left, Mid, and Search in order to pull the values to the left of the first "x", since that will always follow a dimension value.  Can anyone help?

EDIT:  What I am looking for are two columns to populate to the right, one with the first measurement (example one would be parsed to 24 1/2 in Column B) and one with the second (example one would be parsed to 23 1/4 in Column C).

Comment: Please tell us what you want to see in a 2nd, and additional, columns.

Comment: @Mike, I think you're on the right track.  This can probably be done with standard Excel formulas.  Tell me, will there are always be 3 measurements like in your examples? OR will there also be something like "19 x 35" which has just 2?

Comment: Always 3, but the last is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT#1:**

With your text in **A1** , in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"x",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

In **C1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"x",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:B)*999-998,999))
```

Comment: SEXY!  Now I can stick both calculations in a MIN/MAX formula to determine large size, small size.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the column into ColumnB, apply Text to Columns to the copy, with `x` as the delimiter, and delete the column on the right.

Answer (score -1):

Coming up with the answer was the easy part for me.  The hard part is figuring out how to relay it to you.  Drop the table below into your first 2 columns.  The 3rd column will be the result of the formulas:

```
Names     Formulas                                        Results
String    29 1/4 x 13 1/2 x 1 - EXACT
1stX      =FIND("x",B1)                                   8
2ndX      =FIND("x",B1,B2+1)                              17
End       =IF(ISERR(FIND("-",B1)),LEN(B1),FIND("-",B1))   21
1st Arg   =LEFT(B1,B2-2)                                  29 1/4
2nd Arg   =MID(B1,B2+2,B3-B2-2)                           13 1/2
3rd Arg   =MID(B1,B3+2,B4-B3-2)                           1
```

Once you're comfortable with these, you can save space by combining these formulas, i.e. replace `B2` with `FIND("x",B1)`. You can do that to come up with just 1 formula for each argument.

Also, if you need to convert the fractions as regular decimals, use `Value()` to convert them, i.e. 29 1/4 to 29.25.

Comment: @pnuts, when I made these formulae, I put the entire string value `29 1/4 x 13 1/2 x 1 - EXACT` in B1. When my formulas mention B2, it's actually pointing to the 1stX formula.  B3 is the 2ndX and B4 is the end of the number values in the string.

Comment: Good point. I was in a very detail oriented mood yesterday. I do like Gary's Student's answer.  It's much smaller.  Columns() looks interesting.